# How to implement HTML loader for MVC Razor .NET Core requests?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to implement a "loading..." view while the page get the server data and correctly display the window. I've seen many examples with jQuery around, but on all I've seen, they assume my page is using AJAX, while my site is mostly hrefs and form submits.

Is there a way in Razor so the page know when a request have been made and when this request has been answered without using Ajax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this would not be possible, assuming you're not using JavaScript at all. At least, not in the way that you'd imagine. Since it sounds like you're not using any JavaScript on your pages to retrieve data and just using forms to display the same or a different page with the necessary data, you aren't able to change what's on the page you're viewing in between pages since the browser has to reach out to the server to get the new pages/data.

If you're looking to show "loading..." or something after the page loads, but while the data is loading the only option is Ajax or some framework that abstracts it.